# I found the boundary and interior of set and I said that it is closed set. However, I am not sure, so is there anyone who can help me?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

{($x_1,x_2) \in R^2 : x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq 1$} \ {$(1,0)$}

The boundary of set is {($x_1,x_2) \in R^2 : x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1$} and the interior of set is {($x_1,x_2) \in R^2 : x_1^2 + x_2^2 < 1$}. Moreover, I said that it is closed and bounded, but I am not sure. Shall you help me?

Comment: $\{(x_1,x_2) \in \Bbb R^2 : x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq 1\}\backslash \{(1,0)\}$ is **not** closed as the limit point $(1,0)$ is not in the set but it is a bounded set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bounded but not closed. $(1-\frac 1 n ,0)$ is  sequence in the set which converges to $(1,0)$ (which is  not in the set).